# Mongoose Query Performance of find chained by update and direct update in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, performance-testing

I am having performance issues while designing some Web Services in Node.
`I have my project in Node (Express) + Angular JS (Frontend) + MongoDB`
I have one question in my mind regarding Mongoose which is a mongo DB driver for express framework in NODE.

My code is like

```
schema.asn.find({ 'id': id }).update({ 'reprocess_counter': new_reprocess_counter }).exec(function(err, data) {
if (err) {
    return res.send({ status: false, message: "Error while processing." });
}
res.send({ status: false, message: "Changes have been updated " });
});
```

This is the first query for update ... !!

```
schema.asn.update({ 'id': id },{ 'reprocess_counter': new_reprocess_counter }).exec(function(err, data) {
if (err) {
    return res.send({ status: false, message: "Error while processing." });
}
res.send({ status: false, message: "Changes have been updated " });
});
```

This is the second way to perform the update.

**I want to know that which one would perform faster and efficiently ?**

Comment: Here come a new challenger > [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)

Comment: Thanks ... But have you detailed answer for above query ?

Comment: If you want to know which one is faster, try both and do your own benchmark. Then post your answer here, it can help others people.